# Why is my solar charge controller reducing current?

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I have a 60 W, 20 V solar panel and I am trying to charge a 12 V, 70 Ah lead-acid battery with a solar charge controller.

I set the charging voltage to 14.1 V in the controller but it shows the current from solar is 0.5 A at a very sunny time of the day in summer. The max. current of the solar panel is 3 A. Why is the controller limiting the current?

Comment: Because the battery is charged or close to full charge.

Comment: @SolarMike no it is less than 30%.

Comment: Which controller are you using? How are things connected?

Comment: I don't know if it's MPPT or PWM there is no label. the only label written is smart solar charge controller 20A. solar is connected to pv port + - and battery is connected to battery port and a led light is connected to load. @johnEE

Comment: In what test conditions did you measure the 0.5A? Does this value change if you disconnect the LED from the load port?

Comment: I can see it on controller screen. no the load is completely off. there are two amp meters for load and pv visible on controller menu. @johnEE